# Replacing missing absolute time with NA

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a data set absolute time data {absolute time, species} set that looks like this

```
mydata = {{3558297660,74}, {3558297720,38}, {3558297780,61},
  {3558297900,26}, {3558297960,100}, {3558298020,50}, {3558298080,70}, 
  {3558298140,90}, {3558298260, 29}, {3558298320,65}, {3558298380,24}, 
  {3558298500,67},{3558298560,80}, {3558298740,16}, {3558298800,68}};
```

Each time step is 60 s apart, I'm trying to create a continuous data array spaced 60 s apart with missing time entries replaced by the right time and "NA" as below

```
newdata = {{3558297660,74}, {3558297720,38}, {3558297780,61},
  {3558297840,"NA"}, {3558297900,26}, {3558297960,100}, {3558298020,50}, 
  {3558298080,70}, {3558298140,90}, {3558298200,"NA"}, {3558298260,29}, 
  {3558298320,65}, {3558298380,24}, {3558298440,"NA"}, {3558298500,67}, 
  {3558298560,80}, {3558298620,"NA"}, {3558298680,"NA"}, {3558298740,16},
  {3558298800,68}};
```

The main reason why I have sought help of the community is that I intend to use the `DateListPlot` function to plot a `TemporalData` using the `Joined` option which is annoying when there are gaps in the data (as it joins this point, making the plot a bit messy). I have adapted your code for what I want and was wondering if there are options in `DateListPlot` to handle this. I will to plot the data using the joined option but skipping any large time gap or as replacing them with "NA"/`Missing["NA"]`

Comment: I would suggest using `Missing["NA"]` instead, as that's the format easily handled by *Mathematica*.

Answer (score 6):

An alternative to Alexey Golyshev's answer that is more functional programming oriented:

```
data = <|Rule @@@ mydata|>;
{#, Lookup[data, #, Missing["NA"]]} & /@ 
 Range[Sequence @@ MinMax[mydata[[All, 1]]], 60]
```

The idea is to create a lookup table from your data and to create a new list using which is filled using `Lookup`.

Comment: Cool! Short and elegant code. +1

Comment: Thanks @Mathe172. Really helpful

Answer (score 3):

```
ts = TimeSeriesResample[mydata, 60, ResamplingMethod -> {"Constant", "NA"} ]; 

ts == newdata
```

> True

```
DateListPlot[ts]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
newdata = Reap[
   Sow[mydata[[1]]];
   Do[
    diff = mydata[[i + 1, 1]] - mydata[[i, 1]];
    If[diff > 60,
     Sow /@ Table[{mydata[[i, 1]] + 60*j, Missing["NA"]}, {j, Quotient[diff, 60] - 1}]
     ];
    Sow[mydata[[i + 1]]]
    ,
    {i, 1, Length@mydata - 1}
    ]
   ][[2, 1]]

DateListPlot[
 TimeSeries[newdata, MissingDataMethod -> {"Interpolation", InterpolationOrder -> 1}]
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Alexey, managed to get it to work. The main reason why I have sought help of the community is that I intend to use the DateListPlot function to plot a temporal data using the Joined option which is annoying when there are gaps in the data (as it joins this point, making the plot a bit messy). I have adapted your code for what I want and was wondering if there are options in DateListPlot to handle this.

Comment: @LPola See updated answer.

Comment: I got the previous code to work for what I intended. I want to join the continuous point in my data and leave the gaps without interpolating. My amended question was just to check if there's a simpler way to do this using the DateListPlot. But thanks once again for helping.

Answer (score 1):

This a solution using the option [`ResamplingMethod`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ResamplingMethod.html) for `TimeSeries` along with the [`TimeSeriesResample`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TimeSeriesResample.html) built-in:

```
Block[{ts, tsopts, ts2, correctQ},
 With[{tspec = {"Year", "/", "Month", "/", "Day", ", ", "Hour", ":", "Minute", ":", "Second", ".", "Millisecond"}},
   tsopts = Sequence[
     ResamplingMethod -> Missing["NotAvailable"],
     DateFunction -> (DateString[#, tspec] &)
    ];

   ts = Apply[TimeSeries[#2, {#1}, Evaluate[tsopts]] &][Transpose[mydata]];
   ts2 = TimeSeriesResample[ts, Thread[ts[{"FirstTime", "LastTime"}]]];
   correctQ = ts2["Path"] == (newdata /. "NA" -> Missing["NotAvailable"]);

   DateListPlot[
     {ts, ts2},
     PlotLabel -> suggestion == HoldForm[newdata] -> correctQ,
     PlotLegends -> {HoldForm[mydata], suggestion}
    ]
  ]
 ]
```

> [image]

Alternatively, modifying `tsopts` above like in

```
tsopts = Sequence[
  ResamplingMethod -> {"Interpolation", InterpolationOrder -> 0},
  DateFunction -> (DateString[#, tspec] &)
];
```

and replacing everything between the lines starting with `ts2=...` and finishing before `DateListPlot`, with

```
(* check for same dimensions *)
correctQ0 = SameQ @@ (Dimensions /@ {ts2["Path"], newdata});
If[
  correctQ0,
  {correctQ1, correctQ2} = Through[{
    (* same timestamps and values for cases other than NA *)
    And @@ Cases[#, {{t1_, v1_}, {t2_, v2_}} :> True /; t1 == t2 && v1 == v2 && v2 =!= "NA"] &,
    (* same timestamps for cases with NA's *)
    And @@ Cases[#, {{t1_, v1_}, {t2_, v2_}} :> True /; t1 == t2 && v2 =!= "NA"] &
   }[Transpose[{ts2["Path"], newdata}]]],
  correctQ1 = correctQ2 = False
];

correctQ = And @@ {correctQ0, correctQ1, correctQ2};
```

produces the following result:

> [image: Blockquote]